# Advance mysql query with order by

Tags: sql-order-by

I use 2 tables to combine data to become like shown as below

```
SELECT name, price, MIN(price) AS minprice 
FROM c, cp 
WHERE c.id = cp.id 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY minprice = 0, minprice ASC
```

For Example:

```
id     name         price
 1     apple          0
 1     green apple    20
 2     orange         10
 3     strawberry     0
```

As the data result above the minprice of the group 1 is 0 But I don't want the min price take zero, but this is incorrenct if I give condition having minprice > 0 cause

I wanna my result become like this

```
2  orange         10 
1  green apple    20
3  strawberry      0
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```sql
SELECT 
    (
     SELECT name 
     FROM yourtable 
     WHERE price = _inner._MIN AND id = _inner.id LIMIT 1
    ) 
    AS _NAME, 
    _inner._MIN
FROM 
    (
     SELECT id, IFNULL(MIN(NULLIF(price, 0)),0) AS _MIN 
     FROM yourtable 
     GROUP BY id
    ) 
    AS _inner
```

where **yourtable** is the name of your table.

`MIN(NULLIF(price, 0))` allows you to calculate minimum value while not counting a zero.

`IFNULL(<...>,0)` here just means, that we need a real `zero` instead of `NULL` in result.

`LIMIT 1` is on the case if we have an items with the same `id` and `price` but with different `names`. I think, you can freely remove this statement.

Comment: halo, what for '_inner._MIN' use?

Comment: It's just a field in the returned `_inner` subtable designating  calculated field with a minimum item's price. Returned subtable `_inner` acts as a virtual table, except that we ourselves define from which fields it will consist.

Comment: `_MIN` is just an alias for the `IFNULL(MIN(NULLIF(price, 0)),0)` field.